# UsZipCode --> Input -> (zipcode, radius) output -> (List of Zipcodes)

Tags: python, django

This is what I have tried from [this](https://uszipcode.readthedocs.io/uszipcode/search.html#uszipcode.search.SearchEngine.query)

```
search = SearchEngine()
search.query(zipcode="74104", radius="30", returns=5)
```

this returns

> [SimpleZipcode(zipcode='74104', zipcode_type='Standard', major_city='Tulsa', post_office_city='Tulsa, OK', common_city_list=['Tulsa'], county='Tulsa County', state='OK', lat=36.15, lng=-95.96, timezone='Central', radius_in_miles=1.0, area_code_list=['918'], population=12724, population_density=4673.0, land_area_in_sqmi=2.72, water_area_in_sqmi=0.0, housing_units=6606, occupied_housing_units=5794, median_home_value=136200, median_household_income=36848, bounds_west=-95.970417, bounds_east=-95.940281, bounds_north=36.160214, bounds_south=36.13323)]

If I specify radius as an int

```
search = SearchEngine()
search.query(zipcode="74104", radius=30, returns=5)
```

I get

> You can either specify all of `lat`, `lng`, `radius` or none of them

Not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that you can only search by providing the `lat`, `lng` and `radius` parameters, or none of those.

You should not be able to query with just a `zipcode` and `radius`. This is likely a shortcoming of the package, as you get the same results if you searched with `search.query(zipcode=74104, returns=5)`

If you then wanted to find all the other zipcodes within a radius to `74104` you could extract the `lat` and `lng` from your result:

```
results = search.query(zipcode=74104, returns=5) 
# [SimpleZipcode(zipcode='74104', zipcode_type='Standard', major_city='Tulsa', post_office_city='Tulsa, OK', common_city_list=['Tulsa'], county='Tulsa County', state='OK', lat=36.15, lng=-95.96, timezone='Central', radius_in_miles=1.0, area_code_list=['918'], population=12724, population_density=4673.0, land_area_in_sqmi=2.72, water_area_in_sqmi=0.0, housing_units=6606, occupied_housing_units=5794, median_home_value=136200, median_household_income=36848, bounds_west=-95.970417, bounds_east=-95.940281, bounds_north=36.160214, bounds_south=36.13323)]
result = results[0].to_dict()
lat = result['lat']
lng = result['lng']
nearby_zipcodes = search.query(lat=lat, lng=lng, radius=30)
```

Strangely enough, zipcode `74104` is not within the list of zipcodes nearby the lattitude and longitude provided.

Comment: This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239749/python-3-6-uszipcode-print-zipcodes-within-a-radius). I was just wondering if there is any way I can avoid extracting the lat, lng part. For this **zipcode 74104 is not within the list of zipcodes nearby the lattitude and longitude provided** I can probably use the `by_coordinate` method. Thanks for answering.

Comment: I misunderstood your intentions with the title, it seems you want to find all zipcodes within a radius to another zipcode. If you are using the detailed database of 450MB, querying the database twice may lead to performance issues. Besides that I wouldn't worry too much about having to query twice.